# System.getenv() returning VCAP_SERVICES : "******"

Tags: cloud-foundry

`System.getenv()` is returning json with `VCAP_SERVICES : "******"`. My cloud foundry java spring-boot app is bound to three services. If I give `cf env app_name` in CLI, its returning all bound services correctly. Also `VCAP_APPLICATION` and other fields in returned json are just fine except this one.

A Little background:
I need to get service name, label and plan for all the services bound to my app. I'm new to cloud foundry and spring-boot, so don't know how to use spring cloud connectors in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The value in the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable will be a JSON string that you need to parse, and it will give you an object describing all the bound services, including data like name, label, and plan.  If you Google "vcap services" or "cloud foundry environment variables" the first result is [this doc](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html), and it has a [section on `VCAP_SERVICES`](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#VCAP-SERVICES).  Here's the example they provide of what this JSON object looks like (after parsing):

```
{
  "elephantsql": [
    {
      "name": "elephantsql-c6c60",
      "label": "elephantsql",
      "tags": [
        "postgres",
        "postgresql",
        "relational"
      ],
      "plan": "turtle",
      "credentials": {
        "uri": "postgres://seilbmbd:ABcdEF@babar.elephantsql.com:5432/seilbmbd"
      }
    }
  ],
  "sendgrid": [
    {
      "name": "mysendgrid",
      "label": "sendgrid",
      "tags": [
        "smtp"
      ],
      "plan": "free",
      "credentials": {
        "hostname": "smtp.sendgrid.net",
        "username": "QvsXMbJ3rK",
        "password": "HCHMOYluTv"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest wanting to try to to acces this info in your code you should consider the cloud foundry java client, good intro here and its really easy to get up and running. I've found that the api is somewhat limited but its worth looking at - http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/java-client.html